# Logistic Regression doesn't predict for the entire test set

Tags: machine-learning, python, scikit-learn, logistic-regression, kaggle

I am working through Kaggle's Titanic competition.  I am mostly done with my model but the problem is that the logistic regression model does not predict for all of 418 rows in the test set but instead just returns predictions for 197 rows.  This is the error PyCharm gives:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/security/Downloads/AP/Titanic-Kaggle/TItanic-Kaggle.py", line 37, in <module>
    submission = pd.DataFrame({'PassengerId': test['PassengerId'], 'Survived': predictions})
  File "C:\Users\security\Anaconda3\envs\TItanic-Kaggle.py\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 392, in __init__
    mgr = init_dict(data, index, columns, dtype=dtype)
  File "C:\Users\security\Anaconda3\envs\TItanic-Kaggle.py\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\construction.py", line 212, in init_dict
    return arrays_to_mgr(arrays, data_names, index, columns, dtype=dtype)
  File "C:\Users\security\Anaconda3\envs\TItanic-Kaggle.py\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\construction.py", line 51, in arrays_to_mgr
    index = extract_index(arrays)
  File "C:\Users\security\Anaconda3\envs\TItanic-Kaggle.py\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\construction.py", line 328, in extract_index
    raise ValueError(msg)
ValueError: array length 197 does not match index length 418
```

When I `print(predictions)` to confirm, this is what it gives:

```
[0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 0 0
 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 0
 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 1
 1 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0
 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 0]
```

This is my full code:

```
import pandas as pd
import warnings
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

warnings.filterwarnings("ignore", category=FutureWarning)

train = pd.read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/oo92/Titanic-Kaggle/master/train.csv")
test = pd.read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/oo92/Titanic-Kaggle/master/test.csv")

train['Sex'] = train['Sex'].replace(['female', 'male'], [0, 1])
train['Embarked'] = train['Embarked'].replace(['C', 'Q', 'S'], [1, 2, 3])

# Fill missing values in Age feature with each sex’s median value of Age
train['Age'].fillna(train.groupby('Sex')['Age'].transform("median"), inplace=True)

# Creating a new column called "HasCabin", where passengers with a cabin will get a score of 1 and those without cabins will get a score of 0
train['HasCabin'] = train['Cabin'].notnull().astype(int)

train['Relatives'] = train['SibSp'] + train['Parch']

logReg = LogisticRegression()

data = train[['Pclass', 'Sex', 'Relatives', 'Fare', 'Age', 'Embarked', 'HasCabin']]

# implement train_test_split
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(data, train['Survived'], test_size=0.22, random_state=0)

# Training the model with the Logistic Regression algorithm
logReg.fit(x_train, y_train)

predictions = logReg.predict(x_test)
submission = pd.DataFrame({'PassengerId': test['PassengerId'], 'Survived': predictions})

filename = 'Titanic-Submission.csv'
submission.to_csv(filename, index=False)
```

**UPDATE**

As per what the users have pointed out, I went ahead and tried to remedy my mistake (ignore the code repetition. I'll be solving that later):

```
import pandas as pd
import warnings
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

warnings.filterwarnings("ignore", category=FutureWarning)

train = pd.read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/oo92/Titanic-Kaggle/master/train.csv")
test = pd.read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/oo92/Titanic-Kaggle/master/test.csv")

train['Sex'] = train['Sex'].replace(['female', 'male'], [0, 1])
train['Embarked'] = train['Embarked'].replace(['C', 'Q', 'S'], [1, 2, 3])
train['Age'].fillna(train.groupby('Sex')['Age'].transform("median"), inplace=True)
train['HasCabin'] = train['Cabin'].notnull().astype(int)
train['Relatives'] = train['SibSp'] + train['Parch']
train_data = train[['Pclass', 'Sex', 'Relatives', 'Fare', 'Age', 'Embarked', 'HasCabin']]
x_train, x_validate, y_train, y_validate = train_test_split(train_data, train['Survived'], test_size=0.22, random_state=0)

test['Sex'] = test['Sex'].replace(['female', 'male'], [0, 1])
test['Embarked'] = test['Embarked'].replace(['C', 'Q', 'R'], [1, 2, 3])
test['Age'].fillna(test.groupby('Sex')['Age'].transform("median"), inplace=True)
test['HasCabin'] = test['Cabin'].notnull().astype(int)
test['Relatives'] = test['SibSp'] + test['Parch']
test_data = test[['Pclass', 'Sex', 'Relatives', 'Fare', 'Age', 'Embarked', 'HasCabin']]

logReg = LogisticRegression()
logReg.fit(x_train, y_train)

predictions = logReg.predict(test[test_data])
submission = pd.DataFrame({'PassengerId': test['PassengerId'], 'Survived': predictions})

filename = 'Titanic-Submission.csv'
submission.to_csv(filename, index=False)
```

As you can see, I tried to input the select test features into my algorithm

```
test_data = test[['Pclass', 'Sex', 'Relatives', 'Fare', 'Age', 'Embarked', 'HasCabin']]

...

predictions = logReg.predict(test[test_data])
```

Right now, I'm getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/security/Downloads/AP/Titanic-Kaggle/TItanic-Kaggle.py", line 29, in <module>
    predictions = logReg.predict(test[test_data])
  File "C:\Users\security\Anaconda3\envs\TItanic-Kaggle.py\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 2914, in __getitem__
    return self._getitem_frame(key)
  File "C:\Users\security\Anaconda3\envs\TItanic-Kaggle.py\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 3009, in _getitem_frame
    raise ValueError('Must pass DataFrame with boolean values only')
ValueError: Must pass DataFrame with boolean values only
```

Its telling me that I need to pass boolean values into my algorithm but I don't understand why. There wasn't such a prerequisite when I was using the exact same data format while training the model.

Comment: As far as I can see you make changes to the xtrain DF but not to xtest. xtest must have the same logic and shape as xtrain. Otherwise the model will not know what it is supposed to predict. Do the same recoding to xtest like you did to xtrain.

Comment: You only have 197 examples in your x_test set.

Comment: How am I supposed to do that?

Comment: You can write a function and pass dataset to it and in that function, perform all the operation that you want to perform. Then first pass the train dataset and then pass the test dataset. In this way same operations are performed on both dataset and you should not get the error which you are getting now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `predictions` are those for `x_test`, which was split out from `train`, but your `submission`'s `PassengerId`s are those from `test`.

It appears you want to submit predictions for `test`, so you need to call `logReg.predict` on that instead of `x_test`.  However, as @Peter notes in a comment, that will fail since the columns in `test` are not the same as in `train` and therefore `x_train` and `x_test`.  Your feature encodings, null replacement, and engineering need to be done for `test` as well (but take care to to use `train`'s median when filling `test`'s missing ages).

Comment: So does that mean I need to repeat code?  Isn't there a cleaner way of doing that?

Comment: For so few operations, on just two datasets, that's how I'd do it.  You could do as @Vishal suggests, defining a function to apply twice.  You could also combine the two frames, do some of the operations, then split them back apart (but do the imputation separately).

Comment: I took your approach.  Could you check the edit if you don't mind?

Comment: The new error is because of `test[test_data]`; `test_data` is already a dataframe, not the list of columns.  Use just `logReg.predict[test_data]`.

Answer (score 1):

OK, I see your point ... check this code snippet out

you need to adapt it for your 'Titanic-Submission.csv'

the number of predictions will be N = rows

good luck!

https://www.kaggle.com/geoffpidcock/example-submission

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I feel with you that predictions/submissions are hard for beginners but at the same time, I doubt you can expect anyone here to take you step by step through the solution.

Does this code not help you?

https://www.kaggle.com/jlawman/complete-beginner-your-first-titanic-submission

Comment: I went through that website.  The issue isn't the writing the predictions to a CSV file - I already know how to do that.  The problem was that my model was not predicting for the entire test set.